# A warning with building 64bit dll

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, dllimport, dllexport

dll export header

```
extern "C"
void _declspec(dllexport) __stdcall foo();
```

.def file

```
EXPORTS
foo         @1
```

When I build the dll by 64bit build config, I meet this warning.

> warning LNK4197: export 'foo' specified multiple times; using first specification

But If I build the dll by 32bit build config, the warning never occurs.
What is the problem? What is the difference.

In dll header for interface, we usually use this technic,

```
#ifdef EXPORT_DLL
#define BASICAPI _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define BASICAPI _declspec(dllimport)
#endif //_EXPORT_DLL
```

But if def file also exists, we always will be meet the warning when we are building 64bit dll.
So, should we write the codes like this?

```
#ifdef EXPORT_DLL
#define BASICAPI
#else
#define BASICAPI _declspec(dllimport)
#endif //_EXPORT_DLL
```

It works well. But it's not familiar to me.
Give me any your opinions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's generally not good practise to specify exports twice for the same function. If you already have `__declspec(dllexport)` then you do not need to specify the export in a .def file as well. Conversely, if you have the export listed in a .def file, then there's no need for a `__declspec(dllexport)`.

I believe the reason for the warning is that in x86 builds, the `__declspec(dllexport)` is exporting the decorated name with a leading underscore, but the 64-bit compiler does not decorate names with a leading underscore, leading to the duplicate. To verify this, you could look at the 32-bit DLL in Dependency Walker and you should see two exported functions, "foo" and "_foo".

Comment: '64-bit compiler does not decorate names' I didn't know that. That was the reason! Thanks.

Comment: By the way, how can I use Italic font in comment box.

Comment: It *does* decorate names, it just decorates them differently to the 32-bit compiler (i.e. without the leading underscore). You can export a function twice with different names (that's what I expect is happening in your 32-bit builds) the warning is because in 64-bit builds, both the `__declspec` and the .def file would result in the *same* exported name - so one of them is considered redundant.

Comment: You can do italics the same as the question/answer block, by putting \* around the words.

Comment: @Dean I've understood what you said now. I agree. I've just tried that. In 32bit dll, however, the warning never occurs. And only one function has been exported(foo)

Comment: Where is the _foo! The 32 compiler eliminates the spec silently? It never warned to me.

Comment: @Benjamin: Hmm, I won't pretend to know all of the intricacies of the C++ linker, so I'm not really sure what would've happened there... that's what I would have expected to see, but I'm not an expert :)

Comment: @Dean Yes, you are. You helped me enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: And one more thing, If I add *extern "C"*, amd64 builds doesn't decorate a name, but x86 does(_foo@n) about __stdcall

Comment: Iirc the default calling convention for x64 is fastcall, which has different name decoration (none?) than sdcall.

Answer (score 5):

`__declspec(dllexport)` and .def files are two *different* ways to export symbols from a dll. You don't need both and should omit ono of them. The `__declspec` method is far more versatile for c++ programs as it exports names with c++ mangling, allowing overloaded functions to be exported, but conversely that does make the names harder to import via GetProcAddress.

Also, using a generic macro like `EXPORT_DLL` is dangerous as it means that you can't build a dll, that uses another dll, without the one one dll trying to export all the symbols of both dlls.

DevStudio automatically creates a symbol on dll projects: `<PROJECT>_EXPORTS` making it easy and safe to create a EXPORT macro:

```
#ifdef EXPORT
#undef EXPORT
#endif
#ifdef PROJECTNAMEHERE_EXPORTS
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

EXTERN_C EXPORT void __stdcall Function1(void);
EXTERN_C EXPORT void __cdecl Function2(...);
         EXPORT void Function3(void);
```

Functions 1 & 2 can be gotten with GetProcAddress as `_Function1@0` and `Function2` respectively. Function3 is going to be exported via a compiler specific mangled name that will look something like: `@Function3@@UAG_DB@Z`. This name is different for each overload of the function, which is how it allows overloading to work.

Its important to know the name mangling of `__declspec` as .def files don't care and would just export `Function1`, `Function2` and `Function3`.

Comment: Your first paragraph is pretty much what I was trying to say with *my* first paragraph, but you said it much better than me, +1 :)

Comment: Nice answer and comment. +1 :)

Comment: I conversly didn't know about the 64bit thing.